# Understanding a proof idea for fourier inversion

Tags: fourier-analysis

In the book of [Real Analysis by G. B. Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), there's a short proof of the validity of $\mathcal{F^{-1}}(\hat{f})=f,$ when both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ lie in $L^1(\mathbb{R^n}).$

A first lemma used, since both are in $L^1:$
$$
\int \hat{f}g = \int f\hat{g} \tag{1}
$$

Writing down $\mathcal{F^{-1}}(\hat{f})$ direclty does not lead to much since the integrand is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R^n}\times \mathbb{R^n}).$

Instead the author introduces a convergence factor first, only then invokes Fubini's theorem in order to pass to the limit. A rough sketch is given below:

---

Given $t>0,$
Using the lemma in (1):

### $$
\int e^{-\pi t^2 |\xi|^2}e^{2 \pi i \xi \cdot x} \hat{f}(\xi) \, d\xi = \int \hat{f}\Phi= \int f\hat{\Phi}=f*g_t(x) \tag{2}
$$

Where $*$ stands for convolution, and $g_t(x):=t^{-n}\exp{(-\pi |x|^2/t^2)}.$

Since $\int e^{-\pi |x|^2} dx=1$, we have $f*g_t \to f$ in the $L^1$ norm as $t\to 0.$ Finally as $\hat{f}\in L^1$ the dominated convergence theorem yields:

### $$
\lim_{t\to 0} \int e^{-\pi t^2 |\xi|^2}e^{2 \pi i \xi \cdot x} \hat{f}(\xi) \, d\xi = \int e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x} \hat{f}(\xi) \, d\xi = \mathcal{F^{-1}}[\hat{f}](x) \tag{3}
$$

---

- I fail to grasp the whole idea of introducing a convergence factor as was done in (2), and how at the end it allows to prove the validity of fourier inversion in $L^1$ by taking the limit of $t\to 0$ and using the dominated convergence theorem. It would be definitely interesting if someone could shine a light on the intuition behind this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you would like to do, but can't:
$$\begin{align}
\int e^{2\pi i x\xi}\hat f(\xi)\,d\xi&=\int e^{2\pi i x\xi}\Bigl(\int e^{-2\pi i z\xi}f(z)\,dz\Bigr)\,d\xi\\
&=\int f(z)\Bigl(\int e^{-2\pi i (x-z)\xi}\,d\xi\Bigr)\,dz\\
&=f\ast\delta(x)\\
&=f(x),
\end{align}$$
where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta. To make this argument rigorous you multiply by the convergence factor, which is an approximation of the identity (that is, $g_t\to\delta$.) This gives you equation (3). Letting $t\to0$, the right hand side converges to $f$, while the left hand side, by the dominated convergence theorem, to the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat f$.

Comment: The conditions to apply Fubini's theorem are not satisfied. You introduce the convergence factor precisely to be able to change the order of integration: $e^{-\pi t^2 |\xi|^2}f(z)$ is integrable as a function of $(z,\xi)$.